# TypeScript incorrectly throws error TS2769 for Semantic UI fullTextSearch parameter

Tags: typescript, semantic-ui

When I use TypeScript with the Semantic UI search function, I get the following error even though the parameter "fullTextSearch" is present. Why does TypeScript not see it when it is right there?

**Code**

```
   $('#'+this.uiSearch.id)
    .search({
      name: this.name+' Search',
      namespace: "search"+this.uiSearch.id,
      type: 'category',
      source: categoryContent,
      fullTextSearch: "exact",
      maxResults: 30,
      searchFields: ["category", "title", "description"],
      minCharacters: 0,
      onSelect: this.selectEntry,
    });
```

**Error**

```
js/browser/catalogueSelect.js:123:11 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.
The last overload gave the following error.
 Argument of type '{
  name: string; namespace:
  string;
  type: string;
  source: { category: any; title: any; id: any; description: any; }[];
  fullTextSearch: string;
  maxResults: number;
  searchFields: string[];
  minCharacters: number;
  onSelect: (result: any, response: any) => void;
 }'
 is not assignable to parameter of type 'Param'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fullTextSearch' does not exist in type 'Param'.

123           fullTextSearch: "exact",

node_modules/@types/semantic-ui-search/global.d.ts:100:9
100         (settings?: SearchSettings): JQuery;
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
The last overload is declared here.
```

**Documentation**

According to the [Semantic UI Search documentation](https://semantic-ui.com/modules/search.html#/settings):

> fullTextSearch    'exact'     Specifying to "true" will use a fuzzy full
>   text search, setting to "exact" will force the exact search to be
>   matched somewhere in the string, setting to false will only match to
>   start of string. (This setting was previously called searchFullText.)

**Details**

- TypeScript Version 3.7.5
- JavaScript code with JSDoc annotations, executed via `tsc --noEmit`
- package.json includes `"@types/semantic-ui": "^2.2.7"`

P.S.: I misinterpreted the error message, it seems like the "Argument of type" describes the actual input, not the expected one, and the global.d.ts file contains the old parameter name "searchFullText" instead of the new one "fullTextSearch".

Comment: Seems like you already found the source of your error. You could report this in an issue at the [DefinitelyTyped GitHub Project](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped). You can also check to see if you can downgrade semantic-ui to a version that has correct types.

Comment: @CGundlach: That is a good idea, but I just ts-ignored the offending line after learning that it is not a problem with my code. I also created an issue as you suggest but I had already posted it in the Semantic-UI repository, I hope it also gets read over there.

Answer (score 0):

`@types/semantic-ui: "^2.2.7"` is outdated.

It still contains the old "searchFullText" instead of the new "fullTextSearch".
I reported this at: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6961